# How to bind HTML label to Model so that it displays data?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, label, model-binding

I have a list that I am sending to the View from `GET` Method with the help of a `ViewModel`. I plan to send the list data to the `View` just to display it on the screen. I want this label to display the list data one-by-one in the view in a label (since I do not want to edit the data). Then, upon hitting `SUBMIT`, I want the same list data to be sent to the `POST` method where I will be able to save the data. Also, I want to do this without using `HTML Helpers`.

Here is what I have:

**MyView.cshtml**

```
<html>
    ...
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="myTable"> 
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Items</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.MyList.Count(); i++)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        // This is where I want to display the label. 
                        <label name="MyList[@i]">@Model.MyList[i].ToString()</label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</html>
```

**MyController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyMethod(MyViewModel VMObject)
{
    ...
}
```

I am able to display the list contents in the view with `<label name="MyList[@i]">@Model.MyList[i].ToString()</label>`. But, the `ViewModel` object that is returned in `POST` method shows that the list is `null`. Where am I going wrong?

**Edit - 07/31**

**MyViewModel.cs**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    public List<string> MyList { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your view model code? I can't determine what is the object or data type of the List; MyList.

Comment: @JerdineSabio, I have added the ViewModel code. Kindly see the edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to add a hidden input field. Hence your loop will look like;

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.MyList.Count(); i++)
{
   <tr>
     <td> 
       <label>@Model.MyList[i].ToString()</label>
       <input name="MyList[@i]" value="@MyList[i].ToString()" hidden />
     </td>
   </tr>
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about the same, but I wanted to know if there was an easier way (without using hidden fields) to bind the list to the label. I am not even sure if we can bind labels in the first place.

Comment: Here are the form elements that could be passed through Form tag. Apparently I didnt see label there. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_forms

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to use the html helpers you might looking for an ajax request

You could use this script and place this in the click event of your submit button.

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Content("~/*CONTROLLERNAME*/MyMethod")',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: json,
        data:  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)),
        success: function (data) {
        }
    });
```

By using @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) you are converting the View Model into Json data that is readable by the ajax request.